# i want to select only few columns from .csv file in U-SQL Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-lake

i want to select only few columns from .csv file in U-SQL Azure data factory.

have 10 column in my csv file I want to select only 5 columns and write into a new file

Answer (score 1):

When using the built-in extractors you have to specify all columns, but it's easy just to pick only the columns you want  (also known as [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra))) using a rowset variable, like this:

```
// Do the initial extract for all columns
@input =
    EXTRACT colA string,
            colB string,
            colC string,
            colD string,
            colE string,
            colF string,
            colG string,
            colH string,
            colI string,
            colJ string

    FROM "/input/input57.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv();


// Pick (project) the columns you need
@output =
    SELECT colA,
           colB,
           colC,
           colD,
           colE
    FROM @input;


// Output the columns you need
OUTPUT @output
TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```